# Vi on Linux: show ^M line endings for DOS-format files

Tags: linux, vi

On Solaris, if you open a file in vi that has Windows line endings, this shows up as ^M at the end of every line.

On Linux, vi is cleverer and understands the Windows file format, and does not display ^M.

Is there a setting to make Linux vi behave the same as Solaris in this respect?

A common problem for us is copying a shell script off a (Windows) dev box and forgetting to dos2unix it, and then being confused when it doesn't work properly. On Solaris the problem is obvious as soon as you vi the file, but not on Linux.

Thanks.

Comment: On Linux, vi is usually  Bram Moolenaar's **[vim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_(text_editor))**, I expect the vi on Solaris is the Bill Joy [vi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi), original, authentic but less capable.

Comment: On my `vim`, by default I usually see no `^M`, but sometimes there is one at the end of the file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try `:set ffs=unix` when starting vi (or set as default in vimrc) which should display all CR characters as `^M`.

vi auto-guesses which format to use based on whether or not it encounters lines ending in just LF or both CR/LF.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick - On my system, `:set list` shows `$` at the end of all lines (Unix & DOS format), so doesn't help distinguish between the two.

Comment: @sss: My mistake, I'll delete the comment.

Comment: @gman - this command didn't work for me precisely - I got `Not an editor command: ffs=unix` - but set me on the right path.
Running `:set ffs=unix` with the file open in vi didn't work - no error but nothing happened.
I put `set ffs=unix` in my .vimrc file and that worked.

Comment: I experienced exactly the same thing as @sss

Comment: Thus corrupts the carefully prepared user configuration. I most likely want the `ffs` exactly the way it is. But see the answer from @wisbucky.

Answer (score 3):

To show dos line endings for the current file:

`:e +ff=unix`

This forces the fileformat to unix, which will render `CR` as `^M`

---

To make this setting permanent, add to `~/.vimrc`:

`set ffs=unix`

Note that the .vimrc setting is `ffs`, not `ff`.

Comment: This should be `:e ++ff=unix`, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

`:e ++ff=unix`

(per fork0) 54321